# Control Tower Failing to Re-Register OU and even Account Enrollment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

I'm trying to add a new account (created using account factory) in existing OU but the enrollment is failling repeatedly. we're getting this error:

*"AWS Control Tower could not enroll your account for the following reason: AWS Control Tower setup failed. Be sure your account is subscribed to the AmazonCloudFormation service, then try again. If this error persists, contact AWS Support."*

Note: The SSO method was changed to Azure AD after creating the OU and enrolling the first account which was successful, all these errors are coming after this was changed so is this the prime reason and how could I fix it?

On trying to manually enroll the new account, the account is stuck in "Compelete Sign-Up Process" and is asking for payment information which I did not provide for any other account that I created earlier so this doesn't make sense.

Then, we tried to re-register OU, this led to failed enrollment of both accounts, the previous one also which was enrolled earlier.